# 'ClassA' is inappropriate in the namespace 'NamespaceA'

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

Ok I do have the following codes in two files.

**ClassA.vb**

```
Namespace NamespaceA

    Public Class ClassA

        Public Enum RedirectType
          Item1
          Item2
        End Enum

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**ClassX.vb**

```
Namespace NamespaceA

    Public ClassX

       Public Sub MySub
            If ClassA.RedirectType.Item1 Then 'Error occurs here
            End If       
       End Sub      

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Now I am having an error which is

> 'ClassA' is inappropriate in the namespace 'NamespaceA'.

I don't really understand what is inappropriate, how can I fix this? **The two classes resides on the same namespace**. I tried to rename the namespace for the first class but I can't do it because the code is for an existing system. Can someone tell me  what is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Your not using an instance of the class.

Comment: why do a I need to instance it? I am just accessing the enum defined on the class.

Comment: You can't, you have to have a variable of the enum type.

Comment: yes I can. I am telling you I can access an enum of a class without creating an instance of it.

Comment: Check the answer. If you don't have a property of the enum type the compiler tells you `RedirectType` is a `Type` and cannot be used in an expression.

Comment: well I know this would be working but the code is used in an existing system and everything is like this. I can't change it as you wanted. I just wanted to know what its inappropriate.

Comment: Do you make an instance of other types? Same goes for an Enum.

Comment: If you don't make an instance how can you set it, or check it's value?

Comment: it really doesn't need to create an instance to access the enum inside the class as long as its `public` you better try it

Comment: No one said you cannot access it, but that is a type and cannot be set or checked for a value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37909/discussion-between-mahan-and-dona)

Comment: whatis the reason for a downvote?

Comment: I don't know, it was not me.

Comment: Please add Option Strict On to the top of your code file or turn it on in the project properties.  Your If statement needs a Boolean type, not your Enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of the class, and you need a variable of the Enum type so you can set it and checks it value.

```
Namespace NamespaceA
  Public Class ClassA
    Public Property _RedirectType As RedirectType
    Public Enum RedirectType
      Item1
      Item2
    End Enum
  End Class
End Namespace

Namespace NamespaceA
  Public Class ClassX
     Private clsA As New ClassA
     Public Sub MySub
        If clsA._RedirectType = ClassA.RedirectType.Item1 Then
           'now it works
        End If
        If ClassA.RedirectType = ClassA.RedirectType.Item1 Then
           'RedirectType is a Type and cannot be used in an expression
        End If       
     End Sub      
  End Class
End Namespace
```

For `ASPX` make a folder off the `root directory` and place the code files inside this folder which is named the same as the `Namespace` those code files belong to.